# Neural network opencv 3.0

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I am pretty new to neural networks in opencv. I read through the documentation and this is how i have implemented the training of the network

```
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::ANN_MLP> classifier = cv::ml::ANN_MLP::create();


ANN_MLP::Params params;
params.activateFunc = ANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM;
params.layerSizes = layers;
params.fparam1 = 0.6;
params.fparam2 = 1;
params.termCrit = TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER+cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 1000, 0.000001);
params.trainMethod = ANN_MLP::Params::BACKPROP;
params.bpDWScale = 0.1;
params.bpMomentScale = 0.1;
params.rpDW0 = 0.1; 
params.rpDWPlus = 1.2; 
params.rpDWMinus = 0.5;
params.rpDWMin = FLT_EPSILON; 
params.rpDWMax = 50.;




classifier->setParams(params);

int iterations = classifier->train(training_set,ROW_SAMPLE,training_set_classifications);


FileStorage fs("C:\\Users\\Hadi\\Downloads\\output\\param.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);

classifier->write(fs);
fs.release();
```

But on running of the code it is giving me abort error on training part. It is saying something like:

```
Expression Error : Vector subscript out of range
```

Can anybody please guide me to some tutorial for training and predicting of neural networks using opencv 3.0. Thank you.